# How to convert Object to Int

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, type-conversion

I'd like to overload the `getMap` with a Integer value, but the Map only returns an Object. Is there anyway to convert it? Or to have anything similar to C++ auto specifier?

```
public class EventMessage<T> {

    private final Map<EventType, T> messageInput;

    public EventMessage(EventType type, T t) {
        messageInput = new HashMap<EventType, T>();
        messageInput.put(type, t);
    }

    public Map<EventType, T> getMap(){
        return messageInput;
    }

    public T getMap(EventType type){
        return messageInput.get(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create `EventMessage<Integer>` in your code and use Integer.

Comment: `getMap` returns a `T`, if you want it to return `Integer`, you should instantiate an `EventMessage<Integer>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Map and all the Collections store Objects in them. If you want to specify something you should use generics.
For Example for a Map with Integers you should write
`Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();`
Then the Map stores a key-value set of Integers. If you want your Map to be Object and just return an Integer type you should cast the Object to an Integer.